# How to pass Kerberos tickets via Apache server to back-end services

Tags: apache, rest, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego

I have a couple of services running exposed as APIs that are invoked by my Web actions. As of now, there is no authentication on the APIs but make use of user ID being fetched via SSO from my Web application. Now, I plan to make use of Kerberos Authentication even for the APIs for which I am assuming I would need to send (or delegate) the Kerberos ticket to my back-end services.

I am using Apache Server 2.4.6 configured to get user using `mod_auth_kerb` with the below configurations

```
<Location /my-web-site>
AuthType Kerberos  
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User "%{REMOTE_USER}s" env=REMOTE_USER
RequestHeader set X-Auth-User "%{AUTH_USER}s" env=AUTH_USER
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER},NS]
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User "%{RU}e" env=RU
RequestHeader set Remote-User "%{RU}e" env=RU
Header set Remote-User "%{RU}e" env=RU
AuthName "Kerberos Login"
KrbMethodNegotiate on
KrbMethodK5Passwd on
KrbLocalUserMapping off
KrbAuthRealms MY.REALM.COM
KrbServiceName Any
Krb5KeyTab /path/to/my-keytab
require valid-user
</Location>
```

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The Keberos Service Ticket for your Apache httpd server is available in the HTTP Request Header 'Authorization'. As this is not a service ticket for your backendservice it can not actually use it. Why do you need it there?

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr I see that in the Authorization Headers I have negotiation ticket. I need the ticket available so can be used to delegate to kerberized services. 

What I was thinking is that the user ticket can be delegated, rather than the service ticket.

Comment: Normally the backend kerberized service could not decrypt the service ticket issued for your Apache httpd server service.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr how would you typically call a service that is enabled for Kerberos authentication? Or how do you invoke services from SSO?

Comment: You may need something that is somtimes called 'Kerberos delegation', you may look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372734/kerberos-delegation-between-different-services

Comment: Potentially I misunderstood your requirement....

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr Sorry, I think my question wasn't quite clear - so changed it.